# Problems using Sigar with Maven2

Tags: java, maven, jna, sigar

I'm getting errors using Sigar with Maven2.  I understand that it cannot find the Native libraries (dll, or .so) as I know I cannot copy the native libraries into my WEB-INF/lib directory... my question is "How can I copy a directory of lib files into WEB-INF/lib in my WAR file using Maven?

The directory I want to copy FROM is: ${basedir}/lib/
The directory I want to copy TO is: ${webapp.output}/WEB-INF/lib (I think?)

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getLoadAverage()
```

Here is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestAgent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>TestAgent</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.35</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hyperic</groupId>
            <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/sigar.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>        
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <!-- <configuration> section added to pick up the WEB-INF/web.xml inside WebContent -->
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
            <id>eclipselink</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library EclipseLink (JPA 2.0)</name>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure maven war plugin to copy the additional files/folders as illustrated [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html). Something like below.

```
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>lib</directory>
          <!-- override the destination directory for this resource -->
          <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  The target directory seems to make all the files go into a directory deeper called lib.  Its not copying the files from the lib to target :(

Comment: @MikeCurry. Updated `<targetPath>` in the answer above. Does this place the contents correctly?

Comment: No, it seems to make another WEB-INF inside itself (WEB-INF/WEB-INF)

Comment: @MikeCurry. Reverted to the earlier snippet. This works for me with maven war plugin 2.2 and maven-3.0.3.